# What have I done wrong with Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, parallel.foreach

I have the following code with Parallel.ForEach in C#

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var recordList = new List<string> {"1", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"};

        var result = new ConcurrentBag<ProcessedData>();

        Parallel.ForEach<string, ProcessedData>(recordList, () => null //local init
            , (record, state, index, localInit) => //body
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Processing {record}");
                var integerValue = record.Length;
                var processedString = record + " Processed";

                localInit = new ProcessedData
                {
                    IntegerValue = integerValue,
                    StringValue = processedString
                };

                return localInit;
            }, bodyResult => //local finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Adding {bodyResult.StringValue}");
                result.Add(bodyResult);
            });


        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.StringValue}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private sealed class ProcessedData
    {
        internal int IntegerValue { get; set; }
        internal string StringValue { get; set; }
    }
```

When I run the program, I would expect that the console prints out 
"1 Processed", "two processed", "three Processed", "four Processed, "five Processed", "six Processed". However, instead only some items have been processed  !!!

[image]

Do you know what went wrong with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The finally doesn't run that operation *for every item in the collection*.  If you want to perform some operation *for every item in the collection*, that's what the body is for.  The init and finally is for initialization and tear down *of each worker thread*.  So your printouts are telling you that three threads were used in the processing of your items.